# How to validate an .xsd (schema) having <xs-import> tag using schema-validator

Tags: xml, mule

I am trying to validate an schema using the  filter. problem is that It is unable to locate the dependent .xsd which has been mentioned in  tag inside the parent .xsd.
I have used the resourceResolver-ref also but still facing the same issue. Here is sample configuration and class file.

```
<mulexml:schema-validation-filter schemaLocations="${app.home}/sample.xsd" returnResult="false" ref="classpathResourceResolver" name="sample_schema_Validation" doc:name="Schema Validation" />

package org.test.util;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.apache.xerces.dom.DOMInputImpl;
import org.mule.util.IOUtils;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.LSInput;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.LSResourceResolver;

public class ClasspathResourceResolver implements LSResourceResolver {

@Override
public LSInput resolveResource(String type, String namespaceURI, String publicId, String systemId, String baseURI) {

    try {
        InputStream resource = IOUtils.getResourceAsStream(systemId, getClass());
        return new DOMInputImpl(publicId, systemId, baseURI, resource, null);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

I am confused here how can I pass the reference to load my external resources (dependent xsd) ?
Kindly help !!

Answer (score 0):

Is your `sample.xsd` under `src/main/resources`?

Try this: `schemaLocations="${app.home}/classes/sample.xsd"`

Answer (score 0):

Alan Cassar from Ricston team provides a solution for imported xsd resolving in Schema Validation Filter. Please check this link https://www.ricston.com/blog/schema-validation-filter-gotchas/

Answer (score 0):

I take an example to illustrate the solution. Assume that you try to validate against `Mathml2.xsd` which imports a series of other things including `common/math.xsd`.

```
@Override
public LSInput resolveResource(String type, String namespaceURI, String publicId, String systemId, String baseURI) {
    try {
        String path = systemId;
        if (baseURI != null)
            path = URI.create(baseURI).resolve(systemId);
        InputStream resource = IOUtils.getResourceAsStream(path, getClass());
        return new DOMInputImpl(publicId, systemId, baseURI, resource, null);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

The key here is that when resolving an import statement from a resource, the `baseURI` is location of that resource and `systemId` is schemaLocation (usually relative).

**Disclaimer**: for brevity, I skipped the null-checks (systemId can be null in some rare cases which I encountered) and assumed `IOUtils.getResourceAsStream` (never used it from mule package) will retrieve the resource accordingly. The code may not work straight out of the box but it should give you the idea.